# What is the decimal expansion of a real number?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I'm curious as to what the decimal expansion of a real number *is*. Is it an expression? A series? A sequence? What sort of mathematical object is it?

For context, we may define an isomorphism between two Group objects as a Bijective Function mapping from one to the other that "preserves structure." In this sense, an isomorphism IS a function (albeit with some extra requirements).

Likewise, we may define a basis of a vector space as a maximal set of linearly independent vectors. In this sense, a basis IS a set.

Functions and sets clearly represent very fundamental concepts in mathematics. And I'm not asking for a good answer to 'what is a set?'

What I am asking, is what IS a decimal expansion, defined in a way similar to the above? Is a decimal expansion an expression? (Something that exists purely graphically) Is it a sequence of natural numbers? (This might make sense) Is it a series? (This would also make sense).

Comment: It is a sequence of natural numbers. Hence a function, at the end of the day

Comment: @User Thanks for answering. Could you provide a source?

Comment: As an aside, it is not unique. $1=0.\bar{9}$ with the usual notion of convergence.

Comment: While I think this is basically a good question, I would caution against assuming that any given mathematical construct 'IS' only one thing. After all, a sequence of real numbers (for instance) is _also_ a function $f: \mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, and thinking of them in such a fashion is an incredibly useful tool. And of course, a function 'is' a set too; it's a set of ordered pairs $\langle d,r\rangle$ where every $d$ in the domain of the function appears in exactly one ordered pair. You should be ready to switch between seemingly-fundamental representations as needed for any given problem.

Answer (score 2):

We all informally understand what a decimal expansion is, so the particular implementation might differ from situation to situation by what is convenient. One way I have seen is that a decimal expansion is a function $f: \mathbb Z \to \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$ such that there is some $n$ so that $f(m) = 0$ for all $m < n$, together with a number $s \in \{0, 1\}$. This then represents the number
$$
(-1)^s\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z}f(k) \times 10^k,
$$
and is, at least when $m$ is negative, usually written as
$$
f(m)f(m+1)\ldots f(0).f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots
$$
when $s = 0$ or
$$
-f(m)f(m+1)\ldots f(0).f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots
$$
when $s = 1$.

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Comment: No, I have no idea where I read this definition.

Answer (score 2):

A decimal expansion is a series (which implies summation, as opposed to a sequence, which does not).

The series is $$\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}} a_n 10^{i_0 - n}$$
with all $a_n \in \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots , 9\}$ and $i_0 \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Answer (score 0):

> Is a decimal expansion an expression? (Something that exists purely graphically) Is it a sequence of natural numbers? (This might make sense) Is it a series? (This would also make sense).

When defined formally, it is usually defined as a sequence, but can also be formulated as a function. But a precise distinction between "expression", "sequence" and "series" is often not made, which makes such statements as " .999... = 1" problematic. Lay people often interpret this as meaning "If you write a decimal point and then a bunch of nines, that's equal to one if you have enough nines". This leads them to be skeptical of the claim, as they well should be: as an *expression*, the decimal expansion is never equal to one. You can never get to one by writing nines after the decimal point.

As a *sequence*, the decimal expansion isn't *equal* to one; we can say that it *represents* one, but there is a slight difference between a sequence representing a number and it being equal to it.

For " .999... = 1" to be seen as true, it must be interpreted as "The sequence of symbols `decimal point` `nine` `nine` `nine` `ellipsis` represents the number one". And that in turn is true within the framework of series and limits.